# Регулярное выражение с числом кавычек

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Имею таблицу вот с такими данными:

> 132,"Уровень скорости"

В таблице 3к строк, перебирать руками не вышло, думаю попробывать через notepad и регулярное выражение, подскажите с ним. Т.е. возможно ли такая регулярка где будет условие < 2 кавычки или > 2

Comment: Возможно почти все, когда можно понять о чем речь в задаче. правда вопрос, что умеют регулярки в нотепаде ...

Comment: Какой используете язык? Какова общая цель этой обработки?

Answer (score 1):

Нотепада у меня нет, но pspad найдет строки с числом двойных кавычек отличным от 2 такой регуляркой:

```
^[^"]*(("[^"]*){0,1}|("[^"]*){3,})$
```

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, как на счёт нотепада, но в EditPad'у количество кавычек ищется совершенно чётко, например: `["]{2}`. Или вообще, действительно, о чём речь?